# Browse the web via explicit IPv6 without any IPv4 tunnel

Tags: windows-7, ipv6

How can I setup my system to browse the web via an explicit IPv6-*only* IP address *without any IPv4 tunnel*?

I require this for testing IPv6 server testing.

Comment: How do you know that you aren't already using explicit IPv6?

Comment: Not all websites are with only IPv6 address.

Comment: Your modem may not support IPv6

Answer (score 3):

Open your network adapter settings (from Network and Sharing) and disable/uncheck IPv4.

[image: Network Adapter Settings]

Granted, you will need to make sure that your ISP, modem, and router also support IPv6 and have it enabled and configured properly, but from a Windows OS perspective this should force you to use IPv6.

Comment: I am surprised to learn that Windows seems to be ahead of Linux in that respect. Turning off IPv4 to run IPv6-only is something Linux cannot do yet: https://serverfault.com/q/256811/214507

Comment: @kasperd Yes, it's quite strange. But it turns out that MS was an extremely early IPv6 adopter, and this capability goes all the way back to 2008/Vista.

Answer (score 0):

You can either disable IPv4 entirely on your system as has already been proposed, or you can use a plugin specific to your browser(s) to force IPv6 and/or IPv4 connections. For similar testing reasons I use Firefox with the [4or6 plugin](http://www.hunen.net/4or6/) installed.

Comment: The extension has been removed.

Comment: That's unfortunate. I'm still happily using it. A cursory search didn't turn up an alternative with the same functionality.

Answer (score 0):

In Windows Firewall, block outbound traffic from your web browser for the entire set of local IPv4 addresses.

Comment: I'd be willing to try this if there were reasonably detailed instructions.